# While Loop in php not working properly

Tags: php, while-loop

The While Loop is Only Displaying only Last entry

> [image]

```
<table border="5" bgcolor="white" width="300" align="center">
<tr>
    <th bgcolor="grey">User ID</th>
    <th bgcolor="">User Name</th>
    <th bgcolor="grey">User Password</th>
    </tr>
     <?php


     $Load = "select * from sudents";
     $fetch = mysql_query($Load);
     while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($fetch))
      {
        $ID=$rows['id'];
        $User=$rows['user'];
        $Password=$rows['password'];
     }


     echo "<tr> 
        <td>$ID</td>
        <td>$User</td>
        <td>$Password</td>
      </tr>

     ";
       ?>

</table>
```

Comment: Your loop isn't *displaying* anything at all.  Nowhere in this code do you print anything to the page.

Comment: umm .. so what could be wrong? Im Sorry Im Just learning PHP.

Comment: @Cat: Well, what's wrong with the code in this question is that it doesn't print anything to the page at all.  I don't know what code is generating the result in the screen shot you linked, but it's not this code.

Comment: Use `echo $rows['user']` as for an example. If there is any data inside it coming from your query, it should display something.

Comment: @Cat: Put code in the question, not in a comment.  That's entirely unreadable.

Comment: Sorry My Bad, Im New  :< , I Edited my Question.

Comment: while loops tend to not work right if you don't put everything that needs to be in them in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop isn't printing anything to the page.  It's setting values to variables.  And it's over-writing those variable every time.  So when the loop is done, only the *last* values are still set.

Then you just echo that last value.  Once.

Instead, echo the output *inside the loop* so you can have one element of output *for each* loop iteration:

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($fetch))
{
    $ID=$rows['id'];
    $User=$rows['user'];
    $Password=$rows['password'];

    echo "<tr> 
    <td>$ID</td>
    <td>$User</td>
    <td>$Password</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Note, however, that there are a couple of other things wrong here:

1. Your code is vulnerable to XSS attacks.
2. You are ***displaying user passwords***.  Never, *ever* do that.  Your system shouldn't even *have* user passwords in a readable format.  User passwords should be obscured using a 1-way hash and should ***never be retrievable*** by *anybody*.

Comment: Sir, I`m Actually Training my self. That`s not an actual  password its  just some random data inserted in the table for testing although i admits not the best idea to Name is Password. I`m Practicing/Learning PHP. Although i will keep your points in mind when i actually will develop anything. Thank You Very much for your support. I just registered to the site :)

Comment: Sorry, But how can i mark the question as Answered. I can not find the option/button.

Answer (score 1):

As you have it, you are only printing a table row once, and using the last values of the row. All your loop does is assign values to `$ID`, `$User`, and `$Password`, and each loop pass just overwrites the old values. To fix this, you need to move the `echo` statements into the body of the loop.

This will let you print the current values over each iteration, instead of only printing the last. Here's the code that will work for what you want.

```
<table border="5" bgcolor="white" width="300" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th bgcolor="grey">User ID</th>
    <th bgcolor="">User Name</th>
    <th bgcolor="grey">User Password</th>
  </tr>

  <?php

     $Load = "select * from sudents";
     $fetch = mysql_query($Load);

     while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($fetch))
     {
        $ID=$rows['id'];
        $User=$rows['user'];
        $Password=$rows['password'];

        echo "<tr> 
        <td>$ID</td>
        <td>$User</td>
        <td>$Password</td>
        </tr>";
     }

  ?>

</table>
```

Comment: @Cat You're welcome :). When you've had your problem solved, please mark an answer to signify that it's resolved and so that future programmers with a similar issue can find help

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow @Cat I see two problems.

First: no `echo`, `var_dump()` or `print` found.

Second: the while loop will overwrite anything as long as it iterates, so in your case i would push to an array with each result found, like this:

```
<?php
$q = "SELECT id, user, password FROM sudents";
$fetch = mysql_query($q);

$final = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch))  {
    final[] = $row;
}
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>User ID</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>User Password</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($final as $r) {?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $r['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $r['user'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $r['password'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh btw I do recommend you use `mysqli` rather than plain `mysql` since its deprecated. good luck.

Comment: Its Kinda my First ever code of PHP And SQL, Well it something, I will obviously go for MySQLi Once i know basics of MYSQL

Comment: definitely. I would be happy to help you with anything youd like. I actually enjoy doing Teamviewer sessions with people I meet and help explain PHP problems. Do you have any other questions?

Comment: So nice of you. But thats it for now. Would you like to add me on skype? its "faqahat1"

Comment: cool. I added you. Thanks.